# Determining a person's sight from his speech

Tags: optics, visible-light, geometric-optics, lenses

Suppose we meet a person wearing glasses.*Can we determine whether the person is short-sighted or long-sighted*?

However,due to courtesy,we are not allowed to ask him to try the glasses and in general we can't even make any mention of them.

**Attempt at the solution:**
I tried using the image of the eyes but since practically for normal glasses we are at infinity.So the images appear almost the same.

Comment: If this is about physics, more explanation would be helpful. Are you asking whether its possible to evaluate vision without administering an eye test?

Comment: It is kind of a physics puzzle.

Comment: Puzzles can be cool, but if I needed to determine if someone needed eyeglasses I'd ask the to read an eye chart. I think you have another way in mind.

Comment: No,the person already has eyeglasses.We need to determine the type(without actual physical examination).

Comment: Does looking at the type of lens count as physical examination? I think you are over complicating yourself.

Comment: Physical examination refers to actually "touching" the lens which is not allowed.

Comment: And I don't think just seeing the lens from a distance to determine its type is easy.You mentioned using the thickness of lens,but it is really difficult to "see" the variation in thickness.

Comment: Next time you see a person with glasses, look at the corner of his eye or the temporal bone. You'll get what im talking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is simple. For people with myopia (nearsighted) the corrective lenses are concave. In the other case, the corrective lenses are convex. So just by looking at the type of lens you can tell the difference. If the dioptres are small, look to the edges of the lens, there you'll see the difference.